# The Multipart Identifier could not be bound - Checked for spelling already

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01
SET [Case Date_Flag] = 1
WHERE Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01.[Case ID] = Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing.[Case ID]
AND Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing.[Case Date] IS NULL;
```

I have checked for spelling errors, what else could the problem be? The Idea is to populate Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01 with 1's in the Case Date Flag column for the same case ID rows where in Table Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing the case date is null

Comment: You appear to be referencing multiple tables, not just the one you're updating, but haven't supplied a `FROM` clause to pull those tables in.

Comment: So how are you expecting to use `Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing`?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the SQL update writing method;

```
UPDATE Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01
SET [Case Date_Flag] = 1
FROM Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01 A
LEFT JOIN Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing B ON A.[Case ID] = B.[Case ID]
WHERE B.[Case Date] IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just forgetting about a small detail. You have to mention what table you want to update with the new value, or where to find it. Here is an working example:

```
UPDATE U SET FirstName = 'New name'
FROM tblUser U
WHERE U.FirstName = ''
```

Just update your query with a "FROM" statement and maybe use alias as I did in my example above and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the unknown table reference `Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing` in the `WHERE` clause.  You can write the logic like this:

```
UPDATE Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01
    SET [Case Date_Flag] = 1
    FROM Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing
    WHERE Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01.[Case ID] = Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing.[Case ID] AND
          Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing.[Case Date] IS NULL;
```

I prefer using an explicit `JOIN` and table aliases:

```
UPDATE ctclp
    SET [Case Date_Flag] = 1
    FROM Client_Theatres_Cases_Landing_Processing_01 ctclp JOIN
         Client_Theatre_Cases_Landing ctcl
         ON ctclp.[Case ID] = ctcl.[Case ID] AND
          ctcl.[Case Date] IS NULL;
```

Note that a `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate based on the description of what you want to do.  It would set the flag when there is no row in `ctcl`.  If that is what you want to do, then `NOT EXISTS` is a more common approach.